# Geonetwork web interface not running in localhost

Tags: tomcat, http-status-code-404, geonetwork

I followed the steps mentioned [here](https://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/3.10.x/en/install-guide/installing-from-war-file.html)

> ```
> Download the desired geonetwork.war file from SourceForge.
> Copy the WAR file into the webapp folder of Tomcat.
> If started, Tomcat will automatically deploy the application. If not, start Tomcat to deploy.
> ```

I start Tomcat, go to http://localhost:8080/manager/html, and start and click Geonetwork. The page loads for a couple of seconds but the `Start` button doesn't change to `Stop`. It shows `FAIL - Application at context path [/GeoNetwork-4.0.5-0] could not be started`.

[image]

I click GeoNetwork-4.0.5-0 is there and it returns a 404 error.

[image]

**xampp/tomcat/webapps folder**

[image]

**Server information**

[image]

I tried **installing using the [zip file](https://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/3.10.x/en/install-guide/installing-from-zip.html) but now returns a 503 error**

[image]

I checked the log right after starting Tomcat and it says

```
Jul 04, 2022 7:13:30 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\xampp\tomcat\webapps\GeoNetwork-4.0.5-0\WEB-INF\lib\javaee-api-7.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jul 04, 2022 7:13:30 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\xampp\tomcat\webapps\GeoNetwork-4.0.5-0\WEB-INF\lib\jsp-api-2.1-6.1.14.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
Jul 04, 2022 7:13:30 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\xampp\tomcat\webapps\GeoNetwork-4.0.5-0\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.3.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jul 04, 2022 7:13:30 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\xampp\tomcat\webapps\GeoNetwork-4.0.5-0\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jul 04, 2022 7:13:30 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\xampp\tomcat\webapps\GeoNetwork-4.0.5-0\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

Any tips on solving this?

Comment: You can check out the logs in the `tomcat/logs` directory, more information about deployment error should be available there.

Comment: Just for checking: Are you using Java 8?

Comment: @juanluisrp Yes, Java 8 Update 261 (build 1.8.0_261-b12).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're instaling version 4, I would advice to check out the relevant documentation [here](https://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/4.0.x/eng/users/install-guide/installing-from-war-file.html). Some additional services, like ElasticSearch, need to be installed for this version.

Also, it's probably better to download the latest version 4.2.0 instead of an older one, 4.0.5, that you're using.

The error happens most likely due to messy packaging of the war file by the GeoNetwork developers. The file contains libraries that are already provided by Tomcat, so packaging them as part of the war file will result in such error.

The warnings about `servlet-api` and `jsp-api` are not critical, since these libraries are present on Tomcat and will be loaded anyway. However, the `javaee-api-7.0.jar` warning is critical, as Tomcat doesn't fully provide the JavaEE API, and the failure to load this library is the reason the application fails:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.fao.geonet.api.records.attachments.ResourceLoggerStore] from ClassLoader [WebappClassLoader
   context: /GeoNetwork-4.0.5-0
   delegate: false
   repositories:
     /WEB-INF/classes/
 ----------> Parent Classloader:
 java.net.URLClassLoader@2a84aee7
 ]
         at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481)
         at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:321)
         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:267)
         ... 77 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/resource/NotSupportedException
         at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
         at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
         at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
         at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463)
         ... 79 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.resource.NotSupportedException
         at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1951)
         at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1795)
         ... 83 more
```

A quick hack to fix the issue would be to copy this jar from the deployed application (`tomcat/webapps/GeoNetwork-4.0.5-0/WEB-INF/lib/javaee-api-7.0.jar`) to the `tomcat/lib` directory and restarting the Tomcat server.

A proper way would be to report this issue to the developers of GeoNetwork, so that they would remove the conflicting libraries from the distribution or update the documentation.

Comment: Ran it on Tomcat 6 but same result.

Comment: I've updated the answer, with this fix it seems to be working.

Comment: Working now. I also renamed the file to `geonetwork.war` and changed `JAVA_HOME` variable to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_261`. Running Geonetwork 4 with Apache Tomcat/8.5.78. Though I'm getting `Query returned an invalid response` and `Unable to revive connection to http://localhost:9200. Error is Timeout connecting to [localhost/127.0.0.1:9200]` errors in the home page.

Comment: The `localhost:9200` error is most likely related to Elasticsearch which should run locally on the same machine. Did you install it according to the guide?